# C++ 11 regex_match length exact match to given pattern

Tags: c++11

I am in need to compare two given patterns with string and check which pattern is exact match based on number of characters in pattern exactly matched given string. in below example both patterns match but pattern1 is the exact match.
when checked for length returned from regex_match, both will return same matched length.
how to get length excluding special characters ?

```
std::string stringToSearch[] = {"Siva123456789abcdefghiabcdefghjklm123"};
std::string pattern1(Siva123.*abc.*abc.*123);
std::string pattern2(Siva123.*abc.*abc.*12.);

size_t patternLength1 = 0; 
size_t patternLength2 = 0; 

std::smatch matched_elements;
if (std::regex_match(stringToSearch [0], matched_elements, pattern1))
            {
                patternLength1 = matched_elements.length();

            }

if (std::regex_match(stringToSearch [0], matched_elements, pattern2))
            {
                patternLength2 = matched_elements.length();

            }
```

Comment: What does _"which pattern is exact match based on number of characters in pattern exactly matched given string"_ mean? `std::regex_match` always does an exact match, meaning it matches against the entire input string, so the length of the first match will always be the length of the entire input string. I think you are using "exact match" to mean something different, which you haven't explained clearly.

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"? You don't want to count the characters in the pattern?

Comment: OK, I think I see what you're asking, you're defining "exact match" to mean "matched fewer special characters" ... but in that sense neither is exact, because both contain `.*` that matches anything. So you need to clearly define what you consider a better match, then find an algorithm to determine it. Possibly by mutating the input string until one stops matching. e.g. for this specific case if you changed the last character of the input string to `'x'` then pattern1 would stop matching but pattern2 would still match, meaning pattern2 is less precise. That's hard to generalise though.